# Building a NAS: OpenMediaVaultV6, Raspberry Pi4 with Samsung QVO 8TB SSD / BTRFS vs. EXT4 / expected write rates with Wifi V6?

Tags: networking, filesystem, storage, btrfs

I am trying to build a NAS with openmediavault V6.

Hardware:

- Raspberry Pi4 8GB
- Samsung QVO 8TB connected via the lower USB 3.0
- SSD case: https://icybox.de/externe_speicherloesungen/IB-246-C31-G
- Router FritzBox 7530 AX

My MacBook is connected via Wifi V6 5ghz; the Signal is excellent, I am sitting 3m from the router, and the NAS is connected via cable.

I formatted the SSD with BTRFS and connected via samba.
What write speeds should I expect? Currently, I observe around 50mb/s. However I see many people claiming 100mb/s+.

What could be wrong with my setup?

Should I go for Btrfs or ext4?

From my understanding, Btrfs is explicitly designed for SSD drives, but I am not sure how well it is supported by openmediavault?

Comment: *"From my understanding, Btrfs is explicitly designed for SSD drives..."* -> No. https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Hardware.html#solid-state-drives-ssd Also worth a look: https://www.wundertech.net/btrfs-vs-ext4-side-by-side-comparison  WRT openmediavault, I don't see why it would be an issue. https://forum.openmediavault.org/index.php?thread/42547-btrfs/